# send data from one activity to multiple activity

Tags: android

How do we send data of the one activity to another using intent as well as bundle

```
 package in.advaitsolutions.www.broadcast;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
     }
```

Comment: and your question is ... ?

Comment: my question is i want to send data from one activity to multiple activity in same project at same time

Comment: to multiple? and which one should be started?

Comment: see we can send data from one activity to another activity through intent like intent intent = new intent(currentActivity.this,SecondActivity.class)

Comment: start can be any activity it does not matter

Comment: i have no idea what you really want to achieve

Comment: i want to send data from one activity to multiple activity bro

Comment: we can go to the other activity

Comment: and no target activity will be started? so how can you access that data? have you read about [android fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)?

Comment: i have 5 activity and in my main activity i have one edit text and one button something i wrote on text field then i clicked on button send the text from main activity to rest of the 4 activity

Comment: send the same data rest in the 4activity it can be done by a broadcast reciver or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend considering Mediator Pattern or an interface which will be implemented by your receiving activity classes;

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data from one activity to another and so on with **Intent Extras** Like this :

to send data :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name","Florent");
intent.putExtra("age",24);
startActivity(intent);
```

to get data :

```
 getIntent().getIntExtra("age",0)
```

More about [Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

**Or**, you can just use **Shared Preferences** to share data between activities.
Actually, Shared Preferences allow you to save and retrieve data in the form of key,value pair.
Just like this :

to put data :

```
sharedPreferences.edit()
                 .putInt("key_integer", 3)
                 .putString("key_string", "myString")
                 .apply();
```

to get data :

```
int myInteger = sharedPreferences.getInt("key_integer", 0);
String myString = sharedPreferences.getString("key_string", null);
```

More about [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

Comment: i want to do without shared prefrence

Comment: what's wrong with shared preferences ? it solves your problem

Comment: thnx i got can u help in future bro